# How to align the 10 div responsively in different resolution using css

Tags: css

would like to ask for help about my concern. Is there any other way I can maximaze the space of the parent? I have 10 div that need to be align on mobile. In desktop, I wanted to reveal 5 div per row.

I can achieve it using division of every 5 div each per parent but my problem will be on mobile which I usually put 2 div per row.

See my attached image:

[image]

I tried to make it balance but the 5th image will go to bottom.

Here's my css:

```
.dog-cate {
width: 190px;
height: auto;
float: left;
border: #ebe9e9 1px solid;
margin-right: 17px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here's my html:

```
<div class="dog-category">
            <div class="dog-category-container">
                <div class="dog-cate">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="/files/1/2283/6941/files/dog-beds.png?253375352223815948">
                        <span class="dog-cate-title">Dog Beds</span>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="dog-cate">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="/files/1/2283/6941/files/dog-coats.png?253375352223815948">
                        <span class="dog-cate-title">Dog Coats</span>
                    </a>    
                </div>

                <div class="dog-cate">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="/files/1/2283/6941/files/dog-collars-and-leads.png?253375352223815948">
                        <span class="dog-cate-title">Dog Collars &amp; Leads</span>
                    </a>    
                </div>

                <div class="dog-cate">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="/files/1/2283/6941/files/dog-flee-control-and-wormers.png?253375352223815948">
                        <span class="dog-cate-title">Flee Control &amp; Wormers</span>
                    </a>    
                </div>

                <div class="dog-cate">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="/files/1/2283/6941/files/dog-grooming.png?253375352223815948">
                        <span class="dog-cate-title">Dog Grooming</span>
                    </a>    
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="dog-cate">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="/files/1/2283/6941/files/dog-kennels-and-flaps.png?253375352223815948">
                    <span class="dog-cate-title">Dog Kennels &amp; Flaps</span>
                </a>    
            </div>

            <div class="dog-cate">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="/files/1/2283/6941/files/dog-toys.png?253375352223815948">
                    <span class="dog-cate-title">Dog Toys</span>
                </a>    
            </div>

            <div class="dog-cate">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="/files/1/2283/6941/files/dog-training.png?253375352223815948">
                    <span class="dog-cate-title">Dog Training</span>
                </a>    
            </div>

            <div class="dog-cate">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="/files/1/2283/6941/files/dog-travel.png?253375352223815948">
                    <span class="dog-cate-title">Dog Travel</span>
                </a>    
            </div>

            <div class="dog-cate">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="/files/1/2283/6941/files/dog-treatment.png?253375352223815948">
                    <span class="dog-cate-title">Dog Treatment</span>
                </a>    
            </div>
        </div>
```

Is there any good way to fix this kind of issue? Appreciated your help.

Comment: You can probably can do it with flexbox and `justify-content`

Comment: @AlonEitan do you have example how to implement these? so I can see how did you do it as my basis.

Comment: learn about flex

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I wanted to have a specific numbers of div display on specific resolution. I guess flex can't handle that scenario.

Comment: flex can handle everything :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `float:left` will work but its 2018 guys! Use `flexbox` or even `grid`

so I assume your `HTML` is something like this

```
<dog-wrap>
   <pic1>
   <....>
</dog-wrap>
```

**`Flexbox` solution**

```css
.dog-wrap {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
.pic {
    background-color: deepPink;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class='dog-wrap'>
  <div class="pic">afa</div>
   <div class="pic">afa</div>
   <div class="pic">afa</div>
    <div class="pic">afa</div>
    <div class="pic">afa</div>

</div>
```

**`Grid` solution**

```css
.dog-wrap{
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}
.pic {
    background-color: deepPink;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class='dog-wrap'>
  <div class="pic">afa</div>
   <div class="pic">afa</div>
   <div class="pic">afa</div>
    <div class="pic">afa</div>
    <div class="pic">afa</div>
</div>
```

For more info on how they work check the documentation for `flex` and `grid`. And you can work with the gap for space between

Your welcome

Comment: Nicholas - i have a scenario. I tried to use flex but my problem is I can't control how many boxes per row for specific resolution.

Comment: @KobeBryan with flexbox you can work with the width of the item. (or check the flex property). So for example if you want 6 per a row then devide 100% to 6 and assign the value in percentage to width.

With grid its even simpler, you just need to change the value of `grid-template-columns`. Check the oficial docs

With grid you can say heyy I want 5, 6,7,8,or (how much you need) columns. and each column will be an element.

Comment: @KobeBryan 

For example `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 200px);` will make 3 columns with 200px each. Now just play a little bit with it and you can do magic!!

Comment: got it! thank you so much Nicholas! appreciated your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `:last-child` to remove the `margin-right` from the last `.dog-cate` element like so:

```
.dog-cate:last-child {
   margin-right:0px;
}
```

And, for flexibility, use a percentage `width` and `margin` on `.dog-cate`

```
.dog-cate {
  width: 20%; // Adjust to your wishes
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  border: #ebe9e9 1px solid;
  margin-right: 1%; // Adjust to your wishes
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Damian -- the last-child code will not work because i have 10 divs that need to align. In desktop, it should be 5 divs per row. So we can't determine what would be the last child in a specific resolution.